# How do I get a callback from a ManualResetEvent in a Universal app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app

In a universal (windows 10) app, I want to get a callback when a `WaitHandle` is signaled (`ManualResetEvent` in my case). How do I achieve this? Usually I would use `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` but alas, `ThreadPool` went the way of the dodo.

Any other (efficient - non thread blocking) alternatives?

Comment: Are you sure that `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` isn't thread blocking? MSDN says (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a(v=vs.110).aspx): `The wait operation is performed by a thread from the thread pool`

Comment: Also, is the use of a `WaitHandle` a requirement (because provided by an external API), or could you replace it by another object? Because many synchronization cases can be handled by using async/await, task continuation, or simply a callback...

Comment: Use a Task that calls WaitOne().

Comment: @Kookiz: Kind'a. It's blocking, but it does it smartly - for every 32-64 waits, you get one thread blocked.
@Kookiz(2): That's what I ended up doing. I just was reluctant at first to keep recreating the task. Just seemed unclean.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's what I specifically was asking not to do (I don't want to block a thread).

Answer (score 1):

The ThreadPool class in .Net for UWP does not have the method RegisterWaitForSingleObject.

As Hans suggested, you can start a new thread to wait for the signal to workaround.

```
    private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Task.Run(() => {
            mre.WaitOne();

            Debug.WriteLine("do sth else"); 
        });
    }



    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mre.Set(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I specifically asked for a non-thread blocking solution in my question. :) Ah well. Guess we have to wait until it gets re-added.